# OpenSSL Base64 decoding

Tags: openssl

I am trying to use openSSL library for Base64 decoding followed by CMS usage to verify signature.

Below code always print buffer as NULL.

```
char signed_data[] = "MIIO";
int signed_data_length = sizeof(signed_data);

BIO *b64, *bmem;

char *buffer = (char *)malloc(signed_data_length);
memset(buffer, 0, signed_data_length);

b64 = BIO_new(BIO_f_base64());
bmem = BIO_new_mem_buf(signed_data, signed_data_length);
bmem = BIO_push(b64, bmem);

BIO_read(bmem, buffer, signed_data_length);
printf("%s", buffer);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add BIO_set_flags(b64, BIO_FLAGS_BASE64_NO_NL) after the BIO_new() call to tell OpenSSL that all the input appears in a single line without newline.